# Caching and uploading to server in a periodic interval

Tags: java, caching, soa, ehcache

I need to upload data on a periodic interval to the server which gets stored in the SQL(After some processing in BL).

Lets say every 15 mins i have 20000 JSON objects of 1kb each. Whats the best way to implement this.

I thought of writing it to a text , then zip and upload to the server. But now there might be better technologies like EHcache. How should i decide? is it better to use any of these Caching opensource tools ?

There might of 10-100's of clients each sending messages as mentioned earlier to the server.

Comment: For a similar kind of situation we have used Redis in our project. Though in our case size of cached data was not as huge as you have but that wont be a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mongodb sounds the one suitable for your task, because you are talking about caching json documents. 
You can cache the documents as they come in a certain collection, then you can later on sync with a persistent store. 
As compared to other persistent cache like eh, it would offer greater scalability and reliability outside your typical application container, yet would help you easily dump records in a quick and easy way.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/mongodb_advantages.htm

http://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/why-mongodb-popular

Comment: Hey @Shivaprashanth, do let us know what did you went ahead with finally.

Comment: Currently looking at Redis, MongoDB and Ehcache. will take some more days .. I am just thinking why cant we go ahead with plain text files ..

Comment: Hmm  text files are ok for an adhoc solution. Mongo or even redis is not that tough grain to crack. Between mongo and redis the main difference is redis is in memory like a ram and hence blazing fast to boost fast data access, mongo is on the other hand more like a store still fast but more sitting between a cache and a db. There are many traits including those for sharding. However I strongly suggest to move above storing data in text files. These things are easy to learn and not very complex to maintain.